# Modification of Divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For Green's theorem in complex plane , with the help of Cauchy-Riemann equations , we can modify it to become $\iint_B{f^{'}(z)}dxdy=\frac{i}{2} \int_{\partial B}{f(z)}d\overline{z}$
where $d\overline{z}=dx-idy$. Can we do the same for divergence theorem? In other words, can we change the divergence theorem involves only function instead of vector field ?

Comment: What do you mean?  $f$ is a field.  You haven't changed anything to not involve a field with this manipulation of Green's theorem.

Comment: Divergence theorem and Green's theorem are the same thing in the plane. Apply Green's to the field rotated by 90 degrees, and you get divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean, but here's a variant of the divergence theorem:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded $C^1$-domain in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\nu: \partial \Omega \to \mathbb R^n$ denote the outward pointing unit normal to $\partial \Omega$.  Let $\varphi$ be a $C^1$-function. Denote by $e_i$ (for $i=1, \dots, n$) the usual basis vectors of $\mathbb R^n$. Applying the divergence theorem to the vector field $\varphi e_i$ yields
$$\int_\Omega \partial_i\varphi = \int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi \langle \nu, e_i\rangle.$$
Multiplying this with $e_i$ and summing over $i=1, \dots,n$, we obtain that 
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi = \int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi \, \nu.$$
This is a form of the divergence theorem for functions.